# Enthalpy of water using steam tables and specific heat

Tags: thermodynamics

I'm trying to determine the enthalpy of water at 120F. Using the specific heat of water gets me to around 120 Btu/lb. However, using steam tables to get a value for saturated liquid at atmospheric pressure gets me a value of around 88 Btu/lb. What's this difference attributed to and what method is more accurate?

Comment: What is 120 minus 88?  What does that tell you?

Comment: The difference is 32, but I'm not sure what this difference would be attributed to. Is there a difference between saturated liquid and water?

Comment: When you got 120 Btu/lb, it was the result of taking 0F as the datum for determining the enthalpy (i.e., enthalpy = 0 at 0 F) and assuming that you are dealing with liquid water, even though you are below the freezing temperature.  The steam tables use a datum of 32 F (i.e., enthalpy = 0 for liquid water at 32 F, the freezing temperature of water..